# PHP - Rename Korean Letter to English Letter

Tags: php

PHP - Rename Korean Letter to English Letter

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

rename("C:\ep-automatic\못난이 주의보.E021.130617.HDTV.XViD-HANrel.avi", "C:\ep-automatic\Ugly_Alert.E021.130617.HDTV.XViD-HANrel.avi");

?>
```

Error Message:

```
( ! ) Warning: rename(C:\ep-automatic\못난이 주의보.E021.130617.HDTV.XViD-HANrel.avi,C:\ep-automatic\Ugly_Alert.E021.130617.HDTV.XViD-HANrel.avi) [function.rename]: The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2) in C:\wamp\www\saz\aa.php on line 12
```

Initially i wanted use move command but it appear as ? for each korean letter.

Then I think of using php rename, but it like not supporting Korean Letter. Anyone got any idea how do i code it so i can rename a korean file into its english name through php.

Thanks ! I Am running php on a window server

Comment: You should be able to do this from a command prompt if you put quotes around the file name.  `rename "file with korean.dat" "file without korean.dat"`

Comment: I tried using command prompt before. The moment i paste the korean word i copied, it become ??? with ? = 1 korean letter upon paste.

Comment: Sounds like the command prompt doesn't like unicode.  Try something like: `rename "*.E021.130617.HDTV.XViD-HANrel.avi" "newname.avi"`